# Always get "Network connection was lost"as a validation issue

Tags: xcode, validation, app-store

I am trying up upload my first app to the store.  I had a real issue (wrong syntax on version string) first time so I know I can get as far as validation.  When I fixed that issue I now get "Network connect was lost" coming up in the Issues dialog, after quite a pause.

It is not clear if that is a problem with the validation process, between me and apple, or with my app (that does use network connections).  My network is pretty solid.

Any ideas what might be happening.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372318/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1005-the-network-connection-was-lost

Answer (score 30):

I faced the same issue, then i restart my xcode once. The error gone.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes Xcode may cause for issues. So use the "**Application Loader**" to upload app in Appstore.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably caused by unavailability of Apple's servers.

In Apple's developer's forum you can see many people live the same problem at certain times.

The most recent one:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/25437485

So... wait :)

Comment: For anyone Googling, current most recent one (15 Sept 2014): https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6533586

Comment: and me... right now. 2015 Apr 30.... just... waiting... and trying.... over.... and over... :(

Comment: I'm now a proud member of the "waiting for a 700+ Billion dollar company to get its **** together" club

Comment: for me it happened again on 07 May 2016

Answer (score 1):

For me, it succeeds after I change the WIFI my MBP joins.

Comment: This worked for me after I close and open wifi again on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, all I did was Renew DHCP Lease on my Wifi Information, and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

You might have an Agreement e.g. Paid Apps amendment that you need to agree to.

I started to get this issue this morning, after successfully submitting builds for the same app just last night.

Remembered there was something I had to agree to when I was uploading last night (one of the two made it successfully last night despite this agreement issue).

Restarting XCode didn't help me.

Comment: Maybe a little more detail as to the steps you took to finally get this resolved?